# Assigning grades in assembly

Tags: assembly

I have to write a procedure in assembly to assign a letter grade to a student and pass it back to C++ program.

In C++ I am passing

```
extern "C" char LetterGrade (double);
```

```
.data

GradeA REAL4 89.99

GradeB REAL4 79.99

GradeC REAL4  69.99

GradeD REAL4  59.99

_LetterGrade proc

 fld REAL4 PTR [esp + 4]  

 fcom GradeA
 jnbe L1

 fcom GradeB
 jnbe L2

 fcom GradeC
 jnbe L3

 fcom GradeD
 jnbe L4

 mov eax, 'F'
 ret

L1:
 mov eax, 'A' 

 ret

L2:
 mov eax, 'B'

 ret

L3:
 mov eax, 'C'

 ret

L4:
 mov eax, 'D'

 ret

_LetterGrade endp
```

Comment: whats the question? and why isn't this tagged as homework?

Comment: Assembly is a better tag, or so I thought.

Comment: I have to write a function in assembly that assign a letter grade to students after averaging 6 of their grades. As usual 90+ is an A, 80+ but < 90 is a B and so on.

Comment: since the average is a double, I have to work with floating point values and that's what's confusing me. Regular integer values work differently and is something I can do on my own. Assembly Language for x86 Processors 6th edition by Irvine is more confusing then assembly language itself.

Comment: Could you indent your code by four spaces, so it's displayed as a code block?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as I avoid doing homework, I'll instead point you in the direction you need to go:
[A good x86 FPU tutorial](http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/)(specifically, [comparison instructions](http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/fpuchap7.htm)).

`FCOM` does a comparison to the top of the FPU stack, `ST(0)`, so you need to `FLD` the values you check against before you compare them to your source value or visa versa, `FLD` the source, compare vs the 'brackets' you have. then you need to pull out the status word (with `FSTSW`) and check the values with a logical `AND` then jump accordingly.

Comment: Using `fcom m32fp` is fine and the comparison value has been loaded. You are completely correct on needing the FPU status word (control word is different, `FSTSW` is correct) and checking the bits.

Comment: @zooba: yeah, just saw I repeated steps he already had done, well, no harm in stating the correct :P